# tmux 2.1 background transparency

Tags: tmux

I am using tmux 2.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.  I would like to have the background have some transparency.  A lot of times I need to reference something at the same time I use the terminal.

I have looked at http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1  and
[Reset background to transparent with tmux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57700/reset-background-to-transparent-with-tmux#321576)  this seemed to suggest that setting bg=default would do it but it gives me the default solid purple.
I tried using a hex code of #80FFFFFF which tmux rejected.

edit: The old post noted above does not explain how to set the transparency in tmux- at least not to me :(

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ThomasDickey  I did look at that post.  He does say setting bg to default resulted in a transparent status bar but when I tried bg=default it did not work for me.  Also, he is using tmux-powerline.  I was hoping to get a more direct answer to my sito. One of those little things that would make my life much easier.

Comment: Current tmux is >2.5 (May 2017), and the documentation with the obscure clues doesn't apply to 2.1 (that was October 2015).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transparency preferences is not part from tmux, you need to change your `profile preferences` from your `terminal`

`Edit > Profile preferences > Colors`

uncheck `Use transparency from system theme` and

check `Use transparent background`

configure  the level of opacity and that's it

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you referring to? The instructions look very specific.

Comment: I'm refering to the `terminal` application that ubuntu has as default because @RGB said that _"A lot of times I need to reference something at the same time I use the **terminal**."_ Seems to be a `terminal` problem rather than `tmux`

Comment: The OP didn't really mention which terminal emulator they are using (although it is perhaps a valid assumption the OP is using the one you reference). It is definitely *a* terminal issue, rather than something `tmux` can do itself.

Comment: yep :) my assumption based on the distro, configs, and desires from the user... I hope to be right with this, but @RGB will have the last word :)

Comment: @ChristopherDíazRiveros  yes thank you, that is what I was looking for- somehow I thought it was a tmux issue.  Also, although I sain 'when I use terminal' I really meant tmux but this answer solved it.

Comment: tmux use RGB color style by default. If you are using a customized theme in tmux there is a chance the theme is overlapping the terminal colors. You can comment out your custom theme or comment the `set -g window-style` and `set -g window-active-style` from your `~/.tmux.conf` to see if the terminal transparency start to work. If so, you can start to customize your tmux color scheme to have it in the way you want.